# Extract name from scanned qr code (vcard)

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I'm using zxing library to scan QR code, Its working fine. I need to extract the first name & last from that data.

But this line of code is giving me only the first line of QR code.

`String qrContents = result.getContents();`

That's why I can't process the string to get the name from Vcard data.

Please help me to get the name from QR code data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh I got it, simply just need to use string array

`String qrContents[] =result.getContents().split("\n");`